# Do I need an Apple Developer account?

Tags: xcode, macos, dmg

I am newbie in Xcode and Mac.  I can make programs working well on simulators but cant make dmg files . Somewhere I heard I need an Apple Developer account ( 99$) for that but I dont want to publish my file on App store. I just need to install it on 1 or 2 other Macs.

Comment: Getting a Developer Account won't help you create a `.dmg` file... http://digital-sushi.org/entry/how-to-create-a-disk-image-installer-for-apple-mac-os-x/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 21):

With **Xcode 7** you are no longer required to have a developer account in order to **test** your apps on your **Mac** and/or **iOS device**:

[image]

Check it out [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

Please notice that this is the officially supported by Apple, but you'll have to use Xcode 7 or later and your **iCloud account**.

Comment: Xcode Versions <7.0 doesn't allow us to test ios apps on devices without a developer account. Am I right?

Answer (score 9):

Before going on - You **CAN** develop iOS apps and deploy to device from Xcode without developer account, but as far as I know it can be done only on jailbroken devices.

Check [this link](http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/) for more info.

**UPDATE**

sorry, I thought you meant developing for mobile. check [this video about Creation of `.dmg` files](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9Y22JD9IvU) for more information.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Have a look at the [apple developers page](https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/) to see the different account types. Specifically, the free account:

> If you're not ready to join one of our developer programs, you can register as an Apple Developer for free. As a registered Apple Developer you gain access to development tools, resources and information to assist you in creating apps for iOS and OS X. [Learn more](https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/)
>   With the free account you could run your app on any mac OS as well as on an iPhone connected to the mac OS.

With the paid account you could install the app on any provisioning device and submit the app to the store.

Comment: There is no free individual development program for iOS platform which allow you to deploy or debug your application on device (except University): https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/university/

Comment: @Tutankhamen  https://developer.apple.com/programs/register/

Comment: There is no free individual development program for iOS platform ***which allow you to deploy or debug your application on device***

Comment: @Tutankhamen What do you mean by device? mobile?

Comment: I mean that with free account you can only deploy and debug application on emulator, but you can't deploy and debug it on your iPad/iPod/iPhone device.

Comment: @Tutankhamen Actually you can run it on a connected device for debug, and there are ways to [deploy apps without being a member of the developer program](http://246tnt.com/iPhone/#xcode)

Comment: Actually, this is not "official" way and it will work only on jailbroken devices, what isn't, actually, legal.

Comment: @Tutankhamen i know, i've developed app for the appstore in the past. as i said, it is possible to run an app on a device connected by usb to mac os running xcode, totally legal and directly from xcode. to deploy without the usb connectivity one needs the provisional account.

Comment: I've developed for iOS and for other platforms for several years, and I never heard that you can start and debug application on device without paying 99$. Can you give the URL to reference or something.

Comment: @Kuf I would be interested too.

Comment: check this out: [Provisioning Your iOS Device for Generic Development](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/provision_device_for_development-generic.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH1-SW1)

Comment: Ok, here is the answer: **You CAN develope ios apps and deploy to device from Xcode without developer account**

Comment: @evc I've added that to the top of the answer so other will see it clearly. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

If you are developing for the mac and you are not going to publish on mac app store, you do not need a developer account.

You do need an account for any of the following:

- Install an app on an iOS device (even your own one for debugging)
- Publish an app on any of the app stores (either iOS or Mac)

Edit: note that if you do not have an account, your Os X applications will be unsigned. They'll work, but each of your users will get a warning and will need to lower the security settings of his Mac in order to be able to run the application (or, at least, he'll have to approve each application specifically).

Comment: The comments on [Kuf's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12072593/1269037) suggest it might be possible to deploy an app to a connected iOS device without a Developer Account. Do you have a source that can confirm or deny this?

Comment: According to those comments it's only possible for jaibroken devices. Apple does not provide a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You need Developer account for developing and debugging application on device. Of course, there are several ways to do that without this account... Have a look:

http://www.alexwhittemore.com/developing-jailbroken-iphone-ios-401/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an Apple developer account to make apps, but if you want to put them on the App Store, gain access to developer beta release software and forums, then yes you do.

Comment: In general case you'll be unable to deploy/debug you application on-device...

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Mac applications without a membership, but if you want to develop iOS applications, you need a membership to run your app on any device.

If you want to run your iOS app in the iOS Simulator, though, you don't need a membership. You can install Xcode and the iOS Simulator on any Mac running 10.7 Lion or later.

Maybe you want to use the Simulator binaries on other Macs without having to compile the app on the other Macs, then you should have a look at that tool: https://github.com/landonf/simlaunch